# Displaying data in Django by grouping

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Basically, I have worked on this project and I am stuck in displaying the data according to my needs on the html page. Right now all that is shown is the 0-4 data but I'm unsure of how to show it correctly.

For the children:
I want it to show the user's children.

For the timeline:
Depending on which child is selected, the timeline table will show the data from the specific child.I want to group the data by age range (the column headers) and then when clicked, it will show the pdfs associated with the current timeline cell.

My views file:

```
def timeline(request):
    timeline = Timeline.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'timeline.html', {
        'timeline': timeline
    })
```

My model file:

```
HEADER_CHOICES = [
    ('Financial Support', 'Financial Support'),
    ('Educational Support', 'Educational Support'),
    ('Governmental Support', 'Governmental Support '),
    ('Charity Support Groups', 'Charity Support Groups'),
    ('Therapy Support', 'Therapy Support '),
    ('Transport Support', 'Transport Support ')
]
AGE_CHOICES = [
    ('0-4', '0-4'),
    ('4-11', '4-11'),
    ('11-18', '11-18'),
    ('18-25', '18-25')
]

class Timeline(models.Model):
    header = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=HEADER_CHOICES)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=AGE_CHOICES)
    child = models.OneToOneField(Children, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Pdf(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='timelinepdfs')
    timeline = models.ForeignKey(Timeline, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My html page:

```
{% extends 'pages/home_page.html' %}
{% block content %}
<style>
    .rightMenu {

        position:relative;
        float:right;
    }
    .right-caret {

        border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
        border-top: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid #000000;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 0;

    }
    .right
    {
        float:right;
    }

    .thead {
        font-size: 28px;
    }
</style>

<div class="span4">
    <h1> Timeline</h1>

    <label for="child">Choose a Child:</label>

    <select id="child">
        {% for tl in timeline %}
            {% for child in tl.child_set.all %} 
                {% if timeline.child.parent == user.id %}
                <option value="{{child.first_name}}">{{ child.first_name }}  {{ child.last_name }}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}


    </select>

    <form action="{% url 'upload' %}">
        <input type="submit" value="Add to timeline" />
    </form>

    <table class="timeline-table">
    <tr>
        <th>0-4</th>
        <th>4-11</th>
        <th>11-18</th>
        <th>18-25</th>
    </tr>
    {% for tl in timeline %}
    <tr>
        {% if "0-4" in tl.age %}
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                      <h3>{{ tl.header }}</h3>
                       <span class="right-caret right"></span>
                 </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
                    {% for p in Pdf %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group"> <a href="{{ p.url }}" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
                           Download pdf 
                           </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        {% endif %}

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Child model:

```
class Children(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    diagnosis = models.IntegerField(
        choices= DIAGNOSIS_CHOICES,
    )
    disability = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Can you add the Child model?

Comment: @jTiKey just did

Comment: @jTiKey I just fixed the children issue

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it.

Had to do it like this:

views:

```
def timeline(request):
    timeline = Timeline.objects.all()
    children = Children.objects.all()
    pdfs = Pdf.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'timeline.html', {
        'timeline': timeline,
        'children' : children,
        'pdfs' :pdfs
    })
```

page:

```
{% extends 'pages/home_page.html' %}
{% block content %}
<style>
    .rightMenu {

        position:relative;
        float:right;
    }
    .right-caret {

        border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
        border-top: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid #000000;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 0;

    }
    .right
    {
        float:right;
    }

    .thead {
        font-size: 28px;
    }
</style>

<div class="span4">
    <h1> Timeline</h1>

    <label for="child">Choose a Child:</label>

    <select id="child">
        {% for cl in children %}
            {% if cl.parent == user %}
                <option value="{{child.first_name}}">{{ cl.first_name }}  {{ cl.last_name }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}


    </select>

    <form action="{% url 'upload' %}">
        <input type="submit" value="Add to timeline" />
    </form>

    <table class="timeline-table">
    <tr>
        <th>0-4</th>
        <th>4-11</th>
        <th>11-18</th>
        <th>18-25</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        {% for tl in timeline %}
        {% if "Financial Support" in tl.header %}
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                      <h3>{{ tl.header }}</h3>
                       <span class="right-caret right"></span>
                 </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
                    {% for p in pdf %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group"> <a href="{{ p.pdf }}" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
                           Download pdf 
                           </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for tl in timeline %}
        {% if "Educational Support" in tl.header %}
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                      <h3>{{ tl.header }}</h3>
                       <span class="right-caret right"></span>
                 </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
                    {% for p in pdf %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group"> <a href="{{ p.pdf }}" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
                           Download pdf 
                           </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        {% for tl in timeline %}
        {% if "Governmental Support" in tl.header %}
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                      <h3>{{ tl.header }}</h3>
                       <span class="right-caret right"></span>
                 </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
                    {% for p in pdf %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group"> <a href="{{ p.pdf }}" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
                           Download pdf 
                           </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        {% for tl in timeline %}
        {% if "Charity Support Groups" in tl.header %}
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                      <h3>{{ tl.header }}</h3>
                       <span class="right-caret right"></span>
                 </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
                    {% for p in pdf %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group"> <a href="{{ p.pdf }}" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
                           Download pdf 
                           </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        {% for tl in timeline %}
        {% if "Therapy Support" in tl.header %}
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                      <h3>{{ tl.header }}</h3>
                       <span class="right-caret right"></span>
                 </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
                    {% for p in pdf %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group"> <a href="{{ p.pdf }}" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
                           Download pdf 
                           </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        {% for tl in timeline %}
        {% if "Transport Support" in tl.header %}
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                      <h3>{{ tl.header }}</h3>
                       <span class="right-caret right"></span>
                 </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
                    {% for p in pdf %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group"> <a href="{{ p.pdf }}" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
                           Download pdf 
                           </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    </tr> 


    </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Is there a faster way to do it?